# Laravel can not get static resource address

Tags: laravel

In code:

```
 <link href="{{asset('/admin/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It should be request like this:

```
http://www.abcd.com/admin/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css
```

but i got this:

```
http://10.200.15.64:35927/admin/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css
```

and got 404 for static resource

is it a code problem   or  a nginx config problem?

How do I fix this?

Comment: code is in the docker。

Comment: `asset()` links to files within the `public` directory. Is this where the file is?

Comment: Also, have you added your url to the `.env` file as `APP_URL=http://www.abcd.com`

Comment: its a nginx config problem `proxy_pass 10.200.15.64:35927` -> `proxy_pass http://www.abcd.com;`  solved